# value of ::1 for Request.UserHostAddress &Request.UserHostName

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When I inspect Request.UserHostAddress or Request.UserHostName in my controller method, they both have value of ::1. Any ideas why?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the IPv6 localhost address.  (equivalent to `127.0.0.1`)

Comment: is there someway i can start getting my machine ip address?

Comment: That doesn't actually make sense. HTTP requests come from a network adapter; each machine has multiple network adapters.  This request came from the loopback adapter. What are you trying to do?

Comment: capture client ip address and other info for auditing purposes. In order to test it, i would like to get the actualy ip address and not ::1. After all my machine has an ip address of 192.x.x.x and i wonder if there is any way to capture taht

Comment: @palmsnow: `::1` **is** the client IP address.  If the request doesn't come from a loopback adapter, it will be different.

Comment: For my curiosity, is there someway of forcing request not to come from lookback adapter?

Comment: Send a request to your actual IP address rather than localhost.